# Clearing cache of server configuration tool

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Previously I had a different version of WAS (8.5.5.3)  this morning I installed WAS (8.5.5.6) on my laptop.  Also I reinstalled MFP Server to point to new WAS

I started using 'Server configuration tool' then but somehow the tool remembers the old path '/opt/ibm/Websphere/Liberty' and all other old settings

Even I tried removing 'runtime' and 'application' and recreated but still 'tool' picks up the same old details **by default**

Is there any way to clear the old details (or cache) of 'Server configuration tool' ?

Thanks
Sathish kumar

Answer (score 0):

In the current versions of MFP, there is no link between the application server you selected in Install Manager to deploy Application Center, and the application server that is presented first by the Server Configuration Tool when you deploy an MFP Server. The Server Configuration Tool looks at the list of application servers installed with Install Manager and presents them in the order in which it did find them.

Comment: Thank you.  Now, I want to manually create and deploy mobile project war and runtime instead of using 'Server configuration tool'.  Is there any good URL to start off with ?   I find of lots of info but they are not in sequential manner

Comment: If you use the admin that was deployed by the Server Config Tool, this link should be sufficient: http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/c_project_war_file_deploy_manual.html If you also want to deploy the admin service and console manually, follow this first: http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_wlconsole_install_manual.html

Comment: Make sure, if you use and environmentID, to use the same for the runtime or the admin or they won't see each other. SCT uses one.